# Dealing with a nil end_date in a date range scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following scope inside my Campaign model:

```
scope :dashboard_campaigns, ->(start_date, end_date, client_id) {where(client_id: client_id).where('start_date >= ? and end_date <= ?', start_date, end_date)}
```

This scope is gathering `campaigns` within a given date range to be used inside a dashboard.

Sometimes when a user starts a campaign, the `end_date` is not known and is therefore `nil`

If `end_date` is nill, we can assume that a campaign is still active, and therefore should be included in the resulting relation.

I'm just not sure how to write that.  After trying and failing to test for nil within the range statement I'm now thinking of making the default date in the record something like 50years from now until it gets updated by the user.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Postgres supports `infinity`. Don't know if Ruby supports this, but you could try `end_date <= coalesce(?, 'infinity')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using arel and and sql or statement, it seems like you could accomplish it like this:

```
scope :dashboard_campaigns, ->(start_date, end_date, client_id) {
  where(client_id: client_id).where(
    (
      Campaign.arel_table[:start_date].gteq(start_date).and(Campaign.arel_table[:end_date].eq(nil))
    ).or(
      Campaign.arel_table[:start_date].gteq(start_date).and(Campaign.arel_table[:end_date].lteq(end_date))
    )
  )
}
```

Granted, it's a little verbose, but it should work.